# Are Complete Sequences Also Sets with Distinct Subset Sums? (Prime Numbers)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

One of the consequences of Bertrand's Postulate includes that 1 and the series of prime numbers is a complete sequence.

Aditionally, the number of distinct prime partitions of `n` can be seen here: https://oeis.org/A000586, including the formula to generate `a(n)`.

My question is: Is the complete sequence of 1 and the primes also a set with distinct subset sums? If I add any combination of length `L` of 1 and the prime numbers to `s`, is that the only distinct set of primes (and 1) that will add to `s`?

If not, how many additional unique partitions of `s` including  this set of primes and 1 exist such that they are of 
 the length `L`, and each element is used once? Do approximations exist?

Partitions are only considerent "unique" if their elements are different, i.e. order does not count: `{1 + P(2) + P(6)}` is considered the same partition as `{P(2) + P(6) + 1}`. The OEIS link above does not take this into account.

Thank you

Comment: one limiting factor, is the number of primes under n, that may give an upper bound at very least.

Comment: What type of "formula" are you interested in? A generating function? Do you want an exact count, an approximation...?

Comment: @GregMartin An approximation would be of most help (I will edit).

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Why would you need this ?